# Не работает font-awesome из npm

Tags: javascript, html, css, npm

Поставил `font-awesome` так: `npm install --save font-awesome`. После этго пытаюсь получить картинку:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Font awesome -->
    <link href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> fa-camera-retro
</body>
</html>
```

`IntelliJ IDEA` подтверждает, что путь в теге `link` я указал правильно. В результате вижу при запуске сообщение `fa-camera-retro` и никакой картинки. Ошибок в консоле нет. Если подключаю библиотеку через `cdn`, то все работает.

Comment: А шрифты подключены?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо заменить `<link href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">` на `<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">` и все заработает.